# Difference .net 6 and .net 6 isolated for Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dotnet-isolated

With Azure functions what is the difference of using .net 6 and .net 6 isolated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1st Major term between them is .NET 6 belongs to In Process and Isolated belongs to Out-of-Process runtime of the Azure Functions.

[Azure Functions .NET Isolated Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide) official documentation provides you the context on why to use Isolated and benefits of it over In-Process Runtime Languages like .NET 6.

Few Points on .NET 6 vs .NET 6 Isolated on Azure Functions:

1. Tight coupling between the host process and the .NET Function in In-Process runtime because .NET Class libraries share binding APIs & types.
2. Isolated .NET Function Project is an console app that gives you access to the star-up of the function app.

Another [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions) providing the details on functional & behavioral differences wise for running the functions on out-of-process and in-process.

Comment: I would also add the long-term goal that microsoft has is that .net 8 will be the last LTS version that supports in-process. see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-august-2023-roadmap-update/ba-p/3910098

Answer (score 10):

From my point of view the main differences are:

| Feature | In-process | Isolated process |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Development packages | [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) (developed since 2017) | Newer, improved [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker/) (developed since 2021) |
| Middleware | Not supported | Supported |
| Cold start time | Regular Just In Time (JIT) latency | JIT + additionally process launch |

More details on about differences between in-process and isolate worker process .NET Azure Functions you can find in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-in-process-differences).